# Stop executing program starter when moving an other starter over it

Tags: 18.04, xfce

When i move program starter on my desktop to another position and i move it accidentally over an other program starter the other starter is executed. This is annoying. Can i disable this somehow? I'm on Xubuntu 18.04 using Xfce 4.12.

Comment: i mean the *.desktop files that creates symbols on the desktop.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not seeing that. Is moving icons on the desktop something you do often? Are you using a touchpad (if you're on a laptop) or do you have an external mouse?

Comment: sometimes i move icons of course. i use a mouse. this is not a problem of the hardware its something that happens since i used xubuntu for the first time. i think this also accurs with kde (kubuntu). i think this is something absolutely useless.